# How to clip GeoTiff according to shapefile using javascript?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, tiff, shapefile, geotiff

**Situation:** I am plotting data provided in a GeoTIFF file on a map using Reactjs and geoTiff.js. An example of the GeoTiff files I am using is at the following link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yc2Lo5vQrFPAJRe5VklorrvIXuhB1nE0/view.

**What I want to do:** When the user clicks on a specific state (district or any specific shape) then the data provided in the tiff file should be visible only for that shape. Basically, I want to clip the data in the GeoTIFF file according to a given shape (assuming I have the shape boundary definitions. Further the projection system of the shape boundaries and the GeoTiff file are the same).

**Please suggest any approach using georaster, leaflet, georaster-layer-for-leaflet, or some other library.**

Here is the code as of now to show whole tiff data on the map.

**Code:**

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import proj4 from "proj4";
import { useLeafletContext } from "@react-leaflet/core";
import { useMap } from "react-leaflet";
import parseGeoraster from "georaster";
import GeoRasterLayer from "georaster-layer-for-leaflet";

window.proj4 = proj4;

const GeotiffLayer = ({ url, options }) => {
const geoTiffLayerRef = useRef();
const context = useLeafletContext();
const map = useMap();

useEffect(() => {
    const container = context.layerContainer || context.map;

    fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.arrayBuffer())
        .then((arrayBuffer) => {
            console.log(arrayBuffer);
            parseGeoraster(arrayBuffer).then((georaster) => {
                console.log("georaster:", georaster.values[0][1]);
                options.georaster = georaster;
                geoTiffLayerRef.current = new GeoRasterLayer(options);
                container.addLayer(geoTiffLayerRef.current);

                map.fitBounds(geoTiffLayerRef.current.getBounds());
            });
        });

    // return () => {
    //     container.removeLayer(geoTiffLayerRef.current);
    // };
}, [context, url, map, options]);

return null;
};

export default GeotiffLayer;
```

**Output:**

Fig 1 illustrates the whole tiff file shown on the map.
[image: Fig 1 illustrates the whole tiff file shown on the map.]

Fig 2 illustrates the output after a click on the specific state.
[image: illustrates the output after a click on the specific state]

**What I want to do:** When the user clicks on the specific state then tiff data should be shown only for the selected shape, not for other shapes.

**Please suggest any approach using georaster, leaflet, georaster-layer-for-leaflet, or some other library.**